# What is the difference between ridig static actor and kinematic ridig dynamic in Physx

Tags: physx

They all look like static. 
Don't move by the force.
 And can be set position by program.

Answer (score 0):

Though moving static actor is allowed, it is a bad idea since engine must rebuild spacial partitioning structures used for collision detection. Kinematic bodies are not static, so they can be moved "for free".